# Does no one know where the canonical commutation relations come from?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-groups

It's been quite a long time, reading about the origins of the mathematical formulation of quantum mechanics, absolutely no one gives a justified derivation of the canonical commutation relations, even heuristic ideas about the origins of representing the position and the momentum as operators ( or matrices in Heisenberg's paper)..taking in account the amount of the litterature on the subject, this seems quite weird. Is it really that complicated to understand the motivation or the ideas behind Heisenberg first papers on quantum theory?  Any help about this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They basically come in by Noether's theorem and the Euler-Lagrange equations. An invariant physical quantity, e.g. isospin or charge, corresponds to a symmetry group, i.e. a Lie group, that acts as a coordinate transformation without changing the physical quantity. The commutator relations are the multiplication in the Lie algebra, the tangent space of said Lie group.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Noether's theorem is part of Lie theory. E.g. P.J. Olver, Applications of Lie Groups to Differemtial Equations, GTM 107. The question is on the border between mathematics and physics. The original paper from 1918 was published in the "Mathematic physical class" 
https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN252457811_1918

Comment: You can read [Dirac book "The Principles of Quantum Mechanics"](https://www.amazon.com/Principles-Quantum-Mechanics-International-Monographs/dp/0198520115/ref=sr_1_3?crid=397TTX1UJDFXO&keywords=dirac+book&qid=1670448253&sprefix=dirac+book%2Caps%2C95&sr=8-3). Any other thing is a "polishing" of the main idea.

Comment: The "motivation" of  [Heisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg%27s_entryway_to_matrix_mechanics) to found [matrix mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_mechanics#Development_of_matrix_mechanics) was "sudoku/mathematical-dreaming"--there wasn't any, beyond fiddling to fit paradoxical data structures. The commutation relations are a fundamental feature of QM, in the sense that more basic objects leading to it hardly exist. If you *must* go somewhere, go to [phase-space quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-space_formulation).

Comment: Look at this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation

Comment: The canonical commutation relations come from classical mechanics by analogy, not by derivation. You can't deductively come up with Quantum from the classical, but there's a leap you can take that works.